# How to Query Arrays with Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone let me know how to query Arrays with T-SQL?

For example, in the sample table below I would like to query the field 'ce_data' to find the following:

```
where

applicationSubmittedData = 2021-05-17

and

applicationType = personal

and

deceasedDiedEngOrWales = No
```

The sample data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
    ce_data nvarchar(max))

INSERT #tmpTable VALUES
(N'{"declaration":{},"applicationSubmittedDate":"2021-05-17","applicationType":"Personal","deceasedAddress":{},"boDocumentsUploaded":[],"caseType":"intestacy"}'),
(N'{"declaration":{},"applicationSubmittedDate":"2021-05-17","applicationType":"Personal","ihtReferenceNumber":"Not applicable","primaryApplicantEmailAddress":"taqsegzjuixulfrymtxptsxxuucoqsjxxlxp@probatetest.com","deceasedAddress":{},"boDocumentsUploaded":[],"caseType":"intestacy","languagePreferenceWelsh":"No"}'),
(N'{"declaration":{},"applicationSubmittedDate":"2021-05-17","applicationType":"Personal","deceasedAddress":{},"boDocumentsUploaded":[],"caseType":"intestacy"}'),
(N'{"declaration":{},"applicationSubmittedDate":"2021-05-17","applicationType":"Personal","ihtReferenceNumber":"Not applicable","deceasedForenames":"Deceased First Name","primaryApplicantEmailAddress":"soeligorbdrxsdikzjkcswkauhmghnifimhc@probatetest.com","deceasedDiedEngOrWales":"No","deceasedAddress":{"AddressLine1":"test address for deceased line 1","PostTown":"test address for deceased town","AddressLine2":"test address for deceased line 2","PostCode":"postcode","AddressLine3":"test address for deceased line 3"},"deceasedDateOfBirth":"1950-01-01","boDocumentsUploaded":[],"caseType":"intestacy","deceasedForeignDeathCertTranslation":"Yes","languagePreferenceWelsh":"No","deceasedSurname":"Deceased Last Name","deceasedForeignDeathCertInEnglish":"No","deceasedDateOfDeath":"2017-01-01"}')

SELECT * FROM #tmpTable
```

If you use the above sample to help me with this question, after creating the table, your field should look something like this:

[image]

I can't show you what I have done so far, because I haven't got a clue where to begin querying arrays.

Comment: Oh good god, please don't tell me you're storing a whole JSON array in one table value. You should be storing each value from the JSON in its own column then sorting by that. You may also want to look at PostgreSQL if you're using relational data.

Comment: @Kwright02, thanks for reaching out. The table was originally in JSON format. I can't control how the source of the data is stored. I just need to be able query the data as it appears in the table.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to do much except for trying to do some wizardry with like statements. Otherwise, you'd be better off trying to get the data source to store the data into your database differently. If you have control over the storing of the data in the database I can help you, otherwise there isn't much to do unless you sift through the data externally.

Comment: JSON documents are useful for storing composite data as a whole, not for searching over it. Using JSON this way just adds complexity and limits performance. You should consider normalizing the database, and this question would be trivial.

Comment: Actually, are you familiar with Databricks, Apache Spark, or PySpark? The data is stored in JSON format, but I can't show it here on SE as its too big. It can be viewed here. https://gist.github.com/cpatte7372/f9a820e82c5e57befa919430b1b9af45
If you can query data using PySpark, SparkSQL on the data show in my github that would be great. Otherwise, I may need to submit a new question.